# Пара вопросов по индексам SQL

Tags: php, sql

Доброго времени. 
В базе есть два составных индекса для выборки объявлений : всех объявлений и вип(премиум).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вопросы:

1. Нужно ли дублировать во втором индексе колонки, если они уже есть в первом индексе ?
2. Колонки для индекса писал все, что в запросе находятся (после where и order by). Правильно ли это или можно только пару выбрать ?
3. Порядок колонок составлял на основе подсчета  `count(*)`  для каждой колонки и выбирал среднее значение по ней. Правильно ли?
4. Правильно ли я понял, что если выборка используется по одному полю из базы, а  индекс у нас составной, то, в таком случае, индекс не учитывается ?
5. В выборке, если используется оператор `||` , то индекс не учитывается. Почему ?
6. Нужно ли добавлять id_advert в индексы ?

Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

1) Скорее да, чем нет, если порядок не совпадает. Почти однозначно нет, если в более "длинном" индексе имеются все поля из более "короткого", причём строго в начале и строго в том же порядке.

2) Неправильно от слова "совсем". Всё, чего Вы добились - это вместо скана по таблице получили скан по индексу, чуть более компактному. Но он работает именно как компактная таблица, а вовсе не как индекс.

3) Однозначно нет.

4) Нет.

5) Это неверное утверждение.

6) Зависит от запросов, которые Вы собираетесь оптимизировать созданием индекса.

Comment: 4. использую такой запрос
`EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM baza WHERE  n_category= 10;`

n_category  - есть в индексе, но результат запроса  NULL. 

Значит индекс не учитывается все-таки ?

5. Тоже самое, что и в 4 пункте

Comment: Для запроса _SELECT * FROM baza WHERE n_category= 10;_ нужен индекс по одному полю n_category. Или составной индекс, в котором поле n_category стоИт самым первым в списке. Любой другой индекс использоваться не будет.